# An alternate proof of Fuglede's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

To prove [Fuglede's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem) for normal operators on a separable Hilbert space, why does it suffice to show that $E(S_1)T E(S_2)=0$ for all disjoint Borel sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, where $E$ is the spectral measure associated to the given normal operator $N$?

Further, why is this true for $S_1$ and $S_2$ at a positive distance from one another, and how can an approximation by compact sets be used to prove it in the general case?

Comment: This is a very late comment. I strongly recommend those who are instested in this topic to search for the original paper *A COMMUTATIVITY THEOREM FOR NORMAL OPERATORS* of Fuglede.

Answer (score 2):

*(several years later, a comment made this answer resurface so I'm updating it so that it keeps up with the comments. I still don't know how to finish the proof through the outline suggested by Douglas)*

The question comes from this exercise in Ron Douglas' *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory*, Exercise 4.38:

> Given an alternate proof of Fuglede's theorem for normal operators on a separable Hilbert space as follows: Show that it is enough to prove that $E(S_1)TE(S_2)=0$ for $S_1$ and $S_2$ disjoint Borel sets; show this first for Borel sets at positive distance from each other and the approximate form within by compact sets in the general case.

The hypothesis is that $TN=NT$. By the Spectral Theorem,
$$
N=\int_{\sigma(N)}\,\lambda\,dE(\lambda)
$$
for a certain spectral measure $E$, and
$$
N^*=\int_{\sigma(N)}\,\overline\lambda\,dE(\lambda).
$$
By definition, we have that $N$ is a norm-limit of operators of the form $\sum_j\lambda_jE(S_j)$ (i.e. "simple functions"), where $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ is a partition of $\sigma(N)$, and
$$
E(S_j)=\int_{\sigma(N)}\,1_{S_j}(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda).
$$
This last integral, in turn, is a wot limit of integrals of polynomials.

Now, since $TN=NT$, $TN^2=N^2T$, and $TN^k=N^kT$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. So $Tp(N)=p(N)T$ for all polynomials $p$. Then $TE(S_j)=E(S_j)T$ (see the second edit) for Borel sets as above, and so $T$ commutes with all operators of the form $\sum_j\overline\lambda_j\,E(S_j)$. As $N^*$ is a norm limit of such operators, $T$ commutes with $N^*$.

**Edit:** I'll leave the answer above since it is now mentioned in your question. Regarding the condition you care about, you can use it the following way: Let $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ be a partition of the spectrum of $N$. Then
$$
TE(S_j)=ITE(s_j)=\sum_kE(S_k)TE(S_j)=E(S_j)TE(s_j).
$$
So $TE(S_j)=E(S_j)TE(S_j)$. Doing the same process on the right side we get $E(S_j)T=E(S_j)TE(S_j)$. So $TE(S_j)=E(S_j)T$. That is, $T$ commutes with the spectral projections of $N$, and thus it commutes with $N^*$.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Those two spaces, $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$, are in the range of $N$. And $T$ commutes with $N$. So they are invariant for $T$.

Comment: So am I.${\ \ \      }$

Comment: It is certainly true, by Fuglede's Theorem: If $P(N)$ denotes the algebra of polynomials on $N$, then $$P(N)''=(P(N)')'=(P(N,N^*)')'=P(N,N^*)''=W^*(N).$$ Not that I can use this in the proof, though!

Comment: Yes, sorry, that it was I meant! The use of that fact is illicit! :) I'm still dumbfounded by Douglas's concluding remarks. It seems to me that the best way to proceed is to note that spectral projections project onto (sums of) eigenspaces, and since $T$ commutes with $N$, $T$ stabilizes the eigenspaces of $N$. So the $E(S_1)TE(S_2)=0$ for all disjoint choices of $S_i$. (You already covered this, but I deleted my above comments and am repeating it for the benefit of others).

Comment: Please see the second edit.

Comment: I might be missing something, but your second edit seems to contain a mistake. The polynomials in $z$ are certainly not dense in the continuous functions on $\mathbb C$. You need to allow polynomials in $z$ and $\bar z$ to get density. Stone-Weierstrass requires a self-adjoint subalgebra.

Comment: You are right. So again we seem to be running in circles. I'm stumped.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Have you ever figured out an answer? I'm really interested in this question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I just found the original paper *A COMMUTATIVITY THEOREM FOR NORMAL OPERATORS* of Fuglede. I think it is worthwhile to read it.

Comment: @ZhangYuhan: I haven't spent time thinking about this again. So far, I still don't know how to prove the Theorem the way Douglas suggests.